# <SQL Server>DOB and Age field as blank using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a SQL query where I am trying to get both the DOB and Age field as blank (' ') as opposed to `NULL`.

I have managed to use the `ISNULL` function to change the DOB from `1900-01-01` to ' '. Originally my DOB was

```
SELECT isnull(DOB,'') DOB
```

which was bring back `1900-01-01` instead of `NULL`

With the code below the Age field is appearing as '0' rather then ' '. I'm not sure how to use the `ISNULL` function, as the Age field does not exist in the db table.

```
SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DOB) = '1900-01-01' THEN ''
                   ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), DOB, 103) END, '') AS DOB, 
       ISNULL (DATEDIFF(hour,dob,GETDATE())/8766,'')Age,
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks :)

Some dummy data of the table:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB         | Gender | Email        |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road| 2000-12-19 | Male   |Max@mail.net  |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road| null       | Male   |Sam@mail.net  |
```

This is what im getting with my query

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB        | Age  | Email        |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road|2000-12-19 | 15   |Max@Gmail.net |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road|           | 0    |Sam@Gmail.net |
```

What I want to get however is:

```
ID | Name |Address |DOB        | Age  | Email        |
---------------------------------------------------------
01 | Max  |Abc Road|2000-12-19 | 15   |Max@Gmail.net |
02 | Sam  |TBH Road|           |      |Sam@Gmail.net |
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? (Different products, somewhat different SQL.)

Comment: SQL Server is my guess - MySQL uses curdate() and getdate does not appear on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html @Daniel Please update and elaborate

Comment: Give us your table schema with some dummy data

Comment: What's so special with the date 1900-01-01? Why blank and not NULL instead of that date? Which datatype? Don't tell me varchar, use a date/time type!

Comment: First I suggest you to use COALESCE, second it get the precedence of the types used so you can simply cast your result to varchar and use a literal varchar in the null case, third instead of handling it in the DB you can easily just return null and handle how to show it on your UI layer since it's where it belongs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your age:

```
DATEDIFF(hour,dob,GETDATE())/8766
```

It is a number.  To make it a string, do this:

```
cast(DATEDIFF(hour,dob,GETDATE())/8766 as varchar (15))
```

Then you can use isnull because your datatypes are the same

```
isnull(cast(DATEDIFF(hour,dob,GETDATE())/8766 as varchar (15)), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple CASE statement.

```
case
    when dob = ''
        then ''
    else datediff(hour, dob, getdate())/8766
end as [Age]
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do it though.

Comment: Think about your datatypes.  If dob can be an empty string then it's datatype is char or varchar.  That means it can't be used in a datediff function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the other to varchar because it is coming as int then all other cases for that column will come as int if u have'nt mention anything it will default takes 0

so need to change the all output to varchar()

```
SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, DOB) = '1900-01-01' THEN ''
                   ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), DOB, 103) END, '') AS DOB, 

IIf((DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766) is null,'',
cast((DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766) as nvarchar(3))) Age
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nullif` and `cast` for this

```
 select ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(10), nullif(DOB,'1900-01-01'), 103),'')  as DOB,
 isnull(cast(DATEDIFF(hour,nullif(DOB,'1900-01-01'),GETDATE())/8766 as varchar),'') Age
```